# How to choose a specific GPU

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

So I have never build a PC before, I've gamed only on a laptop, but now I like to build my own gaming PC, but I have no idea how to choose a GPU, what I mean is that I have a GPU in mind, it's the RTX 2070, but when I search it up on stores, there are bunch of RTX 2070, the confusing part is the title of the item, it goes like this: RTX 2070 [... gaming] [8GB GDDR6] [Dual HDB Fans..]
It's very difficult to just pick one out. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your question is off-topic here being too broad. It lacks demonstration of appropriate research effort to solve your question (e.g. Have you checked site of the manufacturer? Reviews?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I not so sure how to google this question, I don’t think reviews can help with tell me what the details mean. Maybe this might help, could you tell me what is this GPU’s specs just from the title, I just want to know how to read the title of a GPU.   MSI GAMING GeForce RTX 2070 8GB GDRR6 256-bit HDMI//DP/USB Ray Tracing Turing Architecture HDCP Graphics Card (RTX 2070 ARMOR 8G OC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have decided on a particular range of cards but are struggling to choose a specific card then there are a few things you need to know.

Largely the performance of any of these cards will be very similar with minor bumps in clock speed, cooling solution and potentially quantity or speed of on-board memory.

You are never going to see a wildly different level of performance, but they may be tuned slightly better or manufactured slightly differently.

In the case of cooling solutions you may want to consider whether your case is cramped, typically runs hot or other issues. More fans or larger fans will push the same amount of air while running slower and therefore being quieter. If you always game with headphones on then you might never hear the graphics card fans and so not care, if this is a machine running a gaming/media centre on a TV then the fan noise might be obtrusive so a better cooler and fan could well be appreciated.

In the end though it boils down to whether you are willing to spend an extra fee for what is essentially equivalent to sport tyres over "high performance" tyres on a car. They both do the same job in the long run, but one might help out in some very specific circumstances.  If all you are doing is going to the shop then was the extra cost worth it?